# SDL2_ttf gradient

Tags: sdl, image, interface

I want to render some text using a gradient instead of a solid color, but I can't figure out how to. I first load a gradient like this:

```
SDL_Surface* gradient = IMG_Load("blue-cian.png");
```

then I render the text I'm using:

```
SDL_Surface* text = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, "Text", 30);
```

then I want to blit the text to the gradient but only keeping the pixels inside the text not the ones surrounding it to create a texture and render it to the screen. I guess I need to use SDL_SetSurfaceAlphaMod and/or SDL_SetSurfaceBlendMode to use only the opaque pixels when blitting the two surfaces. But I don't completely understand how that works and I only get either just a square colored with the gradient:

[image: IMG]

or a completely transparent square.

This is how it is supposed to look

[image: IMG]

but I just can't do it, please tell/explain me how to use the rendered text surface as an aplha mask for the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

I've been combing through SDL functions to see if there's anything useful, and I might have found one solution, albeit rather expensive. I'm sure there's a better method out there.

- Create your gradient and text as SDL_Surfaces.
- Process every pixel of the texture's Surface to determine if it is transparent or not. If it **is** transparent, set its color to some arbitrary color you never intend to use.  If the pixel **is not** transparent, set it to be transparent. You should be able to complete this just by using [SDL_GetRGBA](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRGB) and [SDL_MapRGBA](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_MapRGBA).
- [Blit your font surface](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_BlitSurface) onto your gradient surface. This should give you your desired font, but with an opaque background.
- Again, process every pixel; if the pixel's color is equal to the arbitrary color you set it to earlier, set it to be transparent.

This should hopefully give you exactly what you want, but I have not tried it myself. Check out [this post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111239/read-pixels-from-sdl-surface-and-convert-to-color-values) to see a similar example.

Comment: Thank your for your answer but now I am trying to do it with textures instead of surfaces so I posted [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/80177/sdl-render-to-a-texture) besides I don't know how to access pixels from a surface.